# Mover arquivos em python para outra pasta em outro diretório

Tags: python

Amigos,
Preciso mover um arquivo para uma outra pasta em um outro diretório após renomea-lo em **Python**. 
sou iniciante em Python e talvez falte um pouco de visão para resolver o problema. Já tentei mover quando estava renomeando com os.rename, com shutil e nada!

**A pergunta é** : Como fazer para mover este arquivo que acabei de renomear para outra pasta em outro diretório?

```
arquivo = os.rename(arqu, pedido+'.pdf')
```

---

*Segue o codigo completo .*

```
import PyPDF2
import os
import shutil

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\1\Desktop\Escaneados')

for f in os.listdir():
    arqu = (f)
print(arqu)

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(arqu,'rb')  # Importar arquivo
p = reader.getPage(0)
texto = p.extractText()

pos = texto.find("LC")  # Palavra para pesquisar
pedido = (texto[pos:pos + 8])  # +8 caracteres

pos2 = texto.find("Cliente")
cliente = (texto[pos2:pos2 + 40])


arquivo = os.rename(arqu, pedido+'.pdf')
```

Answer (score 2):

Voce pode mover e renomear em um só comando, tanto com o `os.rename` como com o `shutil.move`

```
import os 
import shutil

# Movendo e renomeando com os.rename
os.rename('diretorio/origem/nome-arquivo', 'diretorio/destino/novo-nome-arquivo')

# Movendo e renomeando com shutill
shutil.move('diretorio/origem/nome-arquivo', 'diretorio/destino/novo-nome-arquivo')
```

Veja que basta que mude o nome do arquivo no diretorio destino para que além do `move`, a operação de `rename` seja executada. Em ambos os casos o diretório de destino ja deve existir. No windows, se existir, no diretorio de destino, um arquivo com o mesmo nome para o novo arquivo, será levantada uma excecão.

Observe que de acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html), `shutil.move()` utiliza `os.rename()` quando o destino está no próprio sistema de aquivo em que a função é executada, caso contrário o arquivo de origem é copiado utilizando `shutil.copy2()` para o destino e então é removido.